# Active Directory: how do you pull a list of accounts that belong to a user?

Tags: active-directory

I'm a software developer currently stuck to support CyberArk at a large company. I need to pull up a list of accounts that is belong to a certain user. For example, let's said I have a user account named Bob and I want to find all the accounts that belong to Bob in AD meaning on the Organization tab of a user properties, the Manager should be Bob.

I've absolutely zero knowledge regarding AD except the very basic. Is there a way to do it? I only have access to "Active Directory Users and Computers" tool and I'm not even sure if I have enough privilege to run script or install powershell to do it but would like to know the script or powershell command to do so if there is one.

Comment: Why would a person have more then one account?

Comment: One account is for normal login and another one is for installing software/hardware which have higher privileges. Also, there might be say an application account that is associated with a user as far as I understand.

Answer (score 2):

Install Powershell and the [Quest cmdlets](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx).

Then you could use something like this:

> Get-QADUser -SearchRoot "DC=Company,DC=com" -LdapFilter '(&(manager=cn=Bart De Vos,ou=IT,dc=Company,dc=com)(objectCategory=User))'

You could also use the query in the advanced search box of AD.

```
(&(manager=cn=Bart De Vos,ou=IT,dc=Company,dc=com)(objectCategory=User))
```

You don't need any special rights for this, all members of the domain have full read-access to it.

Comment: Thank you for your tips butI do not have enough permission to run it. sigh...

Comment: @Jack: Try getting the permission, not much you can do otherwise. Make sure to open your powershell with a domainuser that has rights on the DC (Rightclick + Shift on the shortcut -> Run As)

Comment: Even without the Quest (or Microsoft's ActiveDirectory PowerShell module) you can use the provided LDAP query with the built-in DS suite tools: `dsquery * -filter "(&(manager=cn=Bart De Vos,ou=IT,dc=Company,dc=com)(objectCategory=User))"`